# Oracle SqlDeveloper Completion Insight table name with #

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, code-completion

Got following error: if table name contains # (like z#users) code completion does not work.
With normal table names all works fine.

Is there any workarounds? Renaming all tables is not possible.

Sqldeveloper version 4.0.0
Oracle 10.2.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this with a table called ABC#DEF - with both table and column completion in the worksheet, and it worked with no issues.

I'm on 4.0.2 and 11.2.0.4, so an upgrade to our latest SQL Developer patch might help.